# Looking for sorted container in which pointers to elements do not change on addition/removal

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, boost, stl

I am looking for a type of container in which pointers to objects do not change on item addition/removal (even from the middle). Order of items with the same priority can change.

It can be a part of Boost. Ideas?

## Why?

So I can keep objects in one place (one container) and still have them sorted.
There is a need to pass pointers to other objects.

## In case of std::set

Is it safe to store pointers of `MyType` to elements of such a set? The elements are going to be modified by member functions of each, but properties used for comparison will remain intact through lifetime of each object in a set.

Update: in case someone decided to stick with C++ STD or head toward Boost; 
it is worth to look at this: [Boost MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: Please can you clarify your meaning of 'stable'? In the context of sorted containers, normally this means that the order of equal items does not change upon sorting.

Comment: I've updated my question. There was already explanation that I mean the requirement for the behaviour of pointers to objects to be defined (ie.stable) on item addition/removal. That is not the case for std::vector for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (or [std::multiset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset), if stored elements might be the same).

First of all, they are sorted.

Then, on addition/removal operations all references and iterators (if they do not point to the removed element in case of removal) remain unaffected.

For more information about containers and references/iterators invalidation check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules).

Comment: please take a look at an updated version of my question (related to the safety of pointers to modifiable objects) and I shall accept. I would create another question but the very problem is heavily related to the 'stability' of a data structure.

Comment: @Rafal as you are not changing data that is used for sorting you should be fine with `std::set`. Otherwise you can use `boost.multiindex` and sort it anyway you want.

Comment: @Slava I guess, OP won't be fine as `std::set` returns only const iterators, so only const methods are available...

Comment: @EdgarRokyan if objects are stored by pointer then they would be fine, but if stored by value yes that would require `const_cast`, so `boost.multiindex` could be more applicable.

Comment: @Slava that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: after reading what you say; I'm considering two options 1) storing objects by value in a vector and having pointers to them sorted by means of std::set OR 2) using boost.multiindex ; seems like if I got with 1) I would have to take care of managing two different data structures at the same time (deletion etc.)

Comment: @Rafal right, and that exact reason why `boost.multiindex` exists - you do not need to maintain mutiple containers with the same data manually.

Comment: @Rafal I'm not well familiar with boost, but maintaining two data structures instead of one seems to be a bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to keep pointers to objects valid even when iterators get invalidated is to use a container of smart pointers.

To keep sorted containers sorted when inserting, one can use this insertion technique:

```
std::vector<unique_ptr<Object>> v;
unique_ptr<Object> po;

// this will insert new item as the first item of same-value objects within the container
v.insert(std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), po, [](auto& x, auto& y) { *x.get() < *y.get(); }), po);

// this will insert new item as the last item of same-value objects within the container
v.insert(std::upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), po, [](auto& x, auto& y) { *x.get() < *y.get(); }), po);
```